# GridLayout JButton JOptionPane with ActionListener for each button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, joptionpane

I am making a dating game in the style of the Japanese dating game with pictures and responses for fun and practice. I am trying to have a `JOptionPane` message dialog show up for each button in a grid layout as a response to each option. In this way it's like a logic tree. I am not used to using action listener as I am somewhat of a beginner. Here is my code. I am just not used to the syntax of doing this.

Can anyone help me?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.*;
//Implementations of packages

public class NestedPanels extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] BTN_TEXTS = { "Say Hello", "Say You Look Good", "Say Sorry I'm Late" }; //three buttons
   private static final int TITLE_POINTS = 3; //number of objects in text box

   public NestedPanels() { //implemeted class
      JPanel southBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2, 1, 1)); //grid layout of buttons and declaration of panel SoutbtnPanel
      for (String btnText : BTN_TEXTS) { //BTN TEXT button titles linked to string btnText label
         southBtnPanel.add(new JButton(btnText)); //add btnText label
      }
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)); //layout of buttons "Button text"
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(600, 600))); //space size of text box webapp over all
      add(southBtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {//class to show gui
        NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels(); //mainPanel new class of buttons instantiation
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Sim 1.0");//title of webapp on top
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/wchri/Pictures/10346538_10203007241845278_2763831867139494749_n.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        mainPanel.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation
        (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Date Sim 1.0 with we1. Are you ready to play? Yes/No?");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String confirm = in.nextLine();

        if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Ok hot stuff... Let's start.");

            NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Maybe some other time!");

            return;
        }

         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. However, a JOptionPane is a temporary dialog that displays (typically with a message), gets some data from the user and then closes. So you should not be using a Scanner on a GUI. Instead use a JOptionPane to display the message for the user. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples. The tutorial also has a section on How to Write an ActionListener.

Comment: Swing tutorial says these three methods of writing an action listener:
To write an Action Listener, follow the steps given below:

Declare an event handler class and specify that the class either implements an ActionListener interface or extends a class that implements an ActionListener interface. For example:
public class MyClass implements ActionListener { 
but I have already instantiated a parent class of extending the jpanel? any help? the scanner is just utilizing what I know for style and taste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the following to get an idea of how to add action listener to buttons. 
Please note the comments:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NestedPanels extends JPanel {

    private static final String[] BTN_TEXTS = { "Say Hello", "Say You Look Good", "Say Sorry I'm Late" }; //three buttons
    //never used :   private static final int TITLE_POINTS = 3;
    public NestedPanels() {

        JPanel southBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2, 1, 1));
        for (String btnText : BTN_TEXTS) {
            JButton b = new JButton(btnText);
            //add action listener
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    buttonClicked(e);//when button clicked, invoke method
                }
            });

            //alternative much shorter way to add action listener:
            //b.addActionListener(e -> buttonClicked());
            southBtnPanel.add(b);
        }
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //this adds Box to the default  BorderLayout.CENTER position
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(600, 600)));

        add(southBtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    //respond to button clicked
    private void buttonClicked(ActionEvent e) {
        String msg = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand()+" pressed" ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg ); //display button Action
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Sim 1.0");
        //no need to invoke twice frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //no need to invoke twice  frame.pack();
        //no need to invoke twice frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

        /*
         * when posting images, use web resources that anyone can access
         *
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/wchri/Pictures/10346538_10203007241845278_2763831867139494749_n.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

        *this adds label to the default BorderLayout.CENTER position, which is already taken by
        *the Box. Only one (last) component will be added
        mainPanel.add(label);
        *
        */

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //remove all code which is not essential to the question
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to have the picture (Which in the future will be web hosted) and the buttons on borderLayout.CENTER? The whole point is to have the buttons change the picture like in dating sims. Thank you in advance. I was able to make the buttons press-able but took out the picture.

Comment: "Is there anyway to have the picture (Which in the future will be web hosted) and the buttons on borderLayout.CENTER?" Please post a new question. When you do leave me a message here and I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

> but I have already instantiated a parent class of extending the jpanel

Did you look at the example code provided in the tutorial???

The example there "

```
... extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

So all you need is:

```
... extends JPanel implements ActionListener
```

Or in case you need multiple ActionListeners the more flexible approach to create a custom class.

You can use an "annonymous inner class" for the `ActionListener`. Something like:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        String text = button.getText();
        Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, text);
    }
};
```

Then when you create the button you would do:

```
for (String btnText : BTN_TEXTS) 
{
     JButton button = new JButton( btnText );
     button.addActionListener( al );
     southBtnPanel.add( button );
}
```

Comment: Now Java is complaining that "NestedPanels" is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionperformed(ActionEvent) in action listener. Tried to @Override manually but says not applicable.

Comment: Tried at actionperformed method:

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

Comment: `Now Java is complaining that "NestedPanels" is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionperformed(ActionEvent) in action listener.` - did you even read the tutorial and download the code to compile and test it??? The tutorial clearly shows you how to do this. I can't guess what you are doing since you didn't include your code. So read the tutorial

Comment: The methodology works. I simply read the tutorial and used a bit of code from camickr. Next up is using a photo hosted on the internet as well as using different dialog boxes from each button. Thank you!

Comment: @wekruez `The methodology works` - Why was the answer unaccepted? You got the answer to your question. You got a link to the Swing tutorial that is now a reference for future Swing problems. You managed to combine the information I gave you with the tutorial information to problem solve on your own.  If fact because of the tutorial link you now know 3 different ways to use an ActionListener depending on the situation. This approach also shows how to reuse the same ActionListener instead of creating a new ActionListener for each button. This is a good program design as it will save resources.